# Requests Post Запрос

Tags: python, post, requests

Хочу отправить пост запрос на сервер. Есть пример который работает и есть мой код но не могу найти где ошибка. Мой код (даёт ответ 400):

```
URL_SELL_ITEM = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/sellitem/'
params = dict(
    sessionid="d85a7cf2897ac9851a41fec9", 
    appid="730",
    contextid="2",
    assetid="24023336747",
    amount="1",
    price="91"
)
inventary = s.post(URL_SELL_ITEM, params, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
```

Пример который работает: https://github.com/adambard/steam-liquidator/blob/master/liquidator/api.py#L157

Comment: Некоторые данные повторяются в параметре cookies.

Comment: При запросе страницы в текстовом виде мне приходит ответ - {"success":false,"message":"Session mismatch"}   Хотя все куки норм

Comment: такая же проблема. Удалось решить ?